# Integrating x86 assembly in C++ project for old MS-DOS system information program

Tags: c++, assembly, x86-16, masm, cpuid

I'm new to C++ programming and have always wanted to write a system information program for MS-DOS.  I'm currently using the latest DigiMars C++ compiler and MASM 6.13 for my project.  The project settings are for large memory model with a target CPU of an Intel 8088 processor for the widest compatibility with MS-DOS.

I'm attempting to write a routine that checks if the CPU supports the CPUID instruction found on late model 486 and early Pentium CPUs.  I found a couple bits of code through Google searches and have been able to add them to the project and successfully compile, but none of them work.  The problem is that when I attempt to execute the program I get a message about an invalid instruction (under my Windows NT 3.51 test system) and it completely hangs on my test MS-DOS systems.

The code I'm using is as follows:

```
public _is_cpuid_supported

cpuid macro
    db 0fh, 0a2h
endm

_is_cpuid_supported proc near
    .486
    push bp
    mov bp, sp
    sub sp, 40
    push eax
    push ebx
    pushfd                    ; get extended flags
    pop eax
    mov ebx, eax              ; save current flags
    xor eax, 200000h          ; toggle bit 21
    push eax                  ; put new flags on stack
    popfd                     ; flags updated now in flags
    pushfd                    ; get extended flags
    pop eax
    xor eax, ebx              ; if bit 21 r/w then eax <> 0
    pop ebx
    pop eax
    je no_cpuid               ; can't toggle id bit 21, no cpuid here
    mov ax, 1                 ; cpuid supported
    jmp done_cpuid_sup

no_cpuid:
    mov ax, 0                 ; cpuid not supported

done_cpuid_sup:
    mov sp, bp
    pop bp
    ret
_is_cpuid_supported endp
```

I've also tried the sample from OSDev.org here: https://wiki.osdev.org/CPUID?msclkid=3c6e16f9c23611ec98be59859d0dd887 but it doesn't work either.  Any tips?  Let me know if further clarification is needed.

Comment: do you have a debugger that works on this system?

Comment: related, but it will use Dosbox which emulates a CPU. (With no CPUID as far as I know. Still, it could useful to test your program in Dosbox.) https://corexor.wordpress.com/2015/12/04/turbo-debugger-remote-debugging-in-dosbox/

Comment: You don't need a frame pointer or extra stack space, and you could simplify to just `setne al` at the end instead of jumping over `mov` instructions, if you declare it as returning an 8-bit `bool`.  But that looks about right, vs. GCC's `cpuid.h`.  It compiles (to Intel-syntax asm) like so: https://godbolt.org/z/cahGrG81P - with a check for CPUID being supported at all before actually running a CPUID instruction to find the max supported level, when compiled in 32-bit mode (64-bit mode implies CPUID availability).  (Returning 0 if CPUID isn't supported at all, else the level).

Comment: What instruction does your code fault on?  Is it one of the ones in this function, or a later CPUID?  Also, it's weird that you use EBX so you have to save/restore it.  You could use ECX or EDX and clobber it, assuming the 16-bit calling convention your compiler uses also allows that.  BTW, it's not just "early Pentiums" that have CPUID!  It's some late 486 and *every* later x86 CPU, including current ones.

Comment: Source for GCC's CPUID-detection inline asm is https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/config/i386/cpuid.h#L263-L276 but if you need Intel-syntax assembly, the compiler output is probably most useful.

Comment: @PeterCordes `setne` is 386+ not 8086.

Comment: @ecm: So is `pushfd` and `xor eax, 200000h`, which is why I suggested another 386 instruction.  The bit being tested is outside the low 16 in EFLAGS, so this test can't be done without 32-bit operand-size.  Note that this code is after a `.486` directive.  Are you saying that's the bug?  I guess that's possible if this is called without checking for 386.  (This code sequence is normally used in 32-bit mode, where that's already implicit.)  Not sure what a `66h` prefix does on 286, but 8086 has no illegal-instruction #UD fault so it would decode as something.

Comment: @PeterCordes, I'm not sure what instruction it is faulting on, but the error message from NT states:

The NTVDM CPU  has encountered an illegal instruction.
CS:0032 IP:00dd OP:f0 46 02 f8 03

Does that tell you anything?

Comment: @user253751, I can probably get a debugger but sadly I don't know how to use one.  If you can provide some instructions I can give it a try.  If it helps, the debugger will probably be the one that comes with MASM 6.11/6.13.

Comment: @PeterCordes in my C++ code I am performing a basic check that comes with Digital Mars that will detect if the CPU is an 8086/88 through to Pentium, and I am performing a check against that to ensure I am only executing this assembly code on 486 class CPUs or higher.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Oh allright then I just commented without thinking it through. Yes, `setne` in a section in which we already detected a 386 is fine.

Comment: `f0 46` is `lock inc esi`, an illegal instruction (lock prefix for a non-memory operand).  You're probably jumping to non-code for some reason.  Get a debugger and learn to use it; that time investment will very quickly pay for itself when dealing with asm.

Comment: (In 16-bit mode, `f0 46` is `lock inc si`, same "mode" just different operand-size.  Still illegal).  Anyway, I think this code returns correctly to its return address, after restoring the caller's EBX, so this code shouldn't be causing that bug in itself or by violating the calling convention.  So I don't think this is a [mcve] of what's going wrong.  A debugger would be essential for narrowing this down.  A static disassembler might help you figure out where IP = `0x00dd` is inside your code, so you could at least see where the faulting instruction is.

Comment: I would recommend getting a copy of Turbo debugger (you can find in many places online). It is a very good debugger that can handle 386 instructions and is pretty intuitive to use. As mentioned the code looks like it should work outside the context of C++. Have you tried making a test program completely in assembler and see what happens by calling that function? I assume you used `.model large` in your assembly?

Comment: I do find it interesting that you have `proc near` but are using a large model where the default is `proc far`. Have you tried reducing your function to just `ret` to see if it fails?

Comment: @MichaelPetch, I did not specify .model large in the assembly.  I can give it a try.  I can also try removing proc near to leave it at default.  Of course, I will make one change at a time to see the results after each change.

Comment: @MichaelPetch, correction:  I **did** have `.model large` in the assembly.  Also, it looks like removing `far` from the procedure worked!  It compiles and runs properly now.  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I meant removing `near` worked.

Comment: If you just use `proc` without `near` or `far` it will default to the value for the model that is selected.

Answer (score 4):

In `large` memory model DOS programs, the default for assembly procedures is `far`.  Removing the `near` keyword from the line `_is_cpuid_supported proc near` solved the problem.  Thanks to @MichaelPetch for the tip.